# When we have to use multipart: true in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone tell me when and why we use multipart: true in rails.?

---

There are two attributes in form

```
 color:string

 name : string
```

i want to confirm that there is no need of multipart: true, right ?

Comment: I don't understand at all what you are asking, please try to make it a bit more clear what you are trying to do, what you have done, what is not working and in what way we can help you.

Answer (score 15):

`multipart: true` is used, when you have file upload in your form.

Check the [`documentation`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files) on file uploading.

You can go with either `form_tag` with explicit `multipart: true` or with simply `form_for`.

```
<%= form_tag({action: :upload}, multipart: true) do %>
  <%= file_field_tag 'picture' %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :picture %>
<% end %>
```

In your case you don't need `multipart: true`, since you only have attributes `color` and `name`.